# Matlab create new Microsoft Access Database file *.accdb

Tags: matlab, ms-access, database-connection

I have used the following code pattern to access my *.accdb files:

```
accdb_path='C:\path\to\accdb\file\wbe3.accdb';
accdb_url= [ 'jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='''';DBQ=' accdb_path ];
conn = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver',accdb_url);
```

If instead I want to *create* a new *.accdb file, how would I do that?  There is much on the web about how to connect, but I haven't found how to create the *.accdb file itself.

In case it matters, I want to be able to execute SQL 92 syntax.  I am using Matlab 2015b.  I do not want to use the Matlab GUI for exploring databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is based on Tommaso's answer, which provides code for copying an empty `*.accdb` file and connecting to the copy.  Based on an afternoon of trial, error, perusing of the web/help, I've expanded on that to create a database table and export a Matlab table to it.  I've also embedded comments showing where modifications are needed, presumably due to my older 2015b version of Matlab, error catching constructs, and caveats in the file copy.

```
srcPath = [pwd '/emptyFile.accdb'];    % Source
tgtPath = [pwd '/new.accdb'];          % Target
cpyStatOk = copyfile( srcPath, tgtPath );
   % No warning B4 clobber target file

if cpyStatOk
   accdb_url= [ ...
      'jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='''';DBQ=' ...
      tgtPath ];
   conn = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver',accdb_url);
else
   error('Couldn''t copy %s to %s',srcPath,tgtPath);
end % if cpyStatOk

try

   % conn.Execute(['CREATE TABLE tstMLtbl2accdb ' ... Not for 2015b
   curs = conn.exec(['CREATE TABLE tstMLtbl2accdb ' ...
                     '( NumCol INTEGER, StrCol VARCHAR(255) );']);

   if ~isempty( curs.Message )
      % fprintf(2,'%s: %s\n',mfilename,curs.Message);
      error('%s: %s\n',mfilename,curs.Message);
         % Trigger `catch` & close(conn)
   end %if

   % sqlwrite( conn, 'tstMLtbl2accdb', ...Not supported in 2015b
   datainsert( conn, 'tstMLtbl2accdb', {'NumCol','StrCol'}, ...
      table( floor(10*rand(5,1)), {'abba';'cadabra';'dog';'cat';'mouse'}, ...
             'VariableNames',{'NumCol','StrCol'} ) );

catch xcptn

   close(conn)
   fprintf(2,'Done `catch xcptn`\n');
   rethrow(xcptn);

end % try

%
%  Other database manipulations here
%

close(conn)
disp(['Done ' mfilename]);
```

This has been immensely educational for myself, and I hope it is useful for others considering the use of SQL as an alternative to the more code-heavy Matlab counterpart to relational database manipulations.  With this amount of overhead, I'd have to say that it is not attractive to perform SQL manipulations on data residing in the Matlab workspace except where one really needs the hyperoptimization of relational database query engines.

**To those savvy with interfacing to Access, your comment on the purpose of the field names argument of the `datainsert` function would be appreciated.**  It is dubbed `colnames` in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.datainsert.html).  From testing, the field names and number of columns must match between the existing target table in Access and the source table in Matlab.  So the field names argument doesn't seem to serve any purpose.  The help documentation isn't all that helpful.

**AFTERNOTE:** I've composed a "specification" for the `colnams` argument based on examples from TMW.  TMW has confirmed this explanation:

> The `colnames` argument tells the external database environment the names and order of fields of the data container supplied via the `data` argument.  These field names are used to match the fields of the transferred data with fields in the table `tablename` residing within the external database environment.  Because of this explicit name matching, the order of the fields in `data` do not have to match the order of the fields in `tablename`.

If I find any departures of empirical behaviour from the above "specification", I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are attempting to do can be very tricky to achieve. It may require a direct interface to Access through an `ActiveX` control and I'm not even sure it can be done. It seems that the web is lacking a solid information pool concerning Access interoperability.

One quick workaround I can suggest you, althrough miserable, is to manually create an empty `ACCDB` file that you can use as template and then duplicate it whenever a new database must be created:

```
conn = CreateDB('C:\PathB\wbe3.accdb');

function accdb_conn = CreateDB(accdb_path)
    status = copyfile('C:\PathA\template.accdb',accdb_path,'f');

    if (status)
        accdb_url = ['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=' accdb_path];
        accdb_conn = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver',accdb_url);
    else
        accdb_conn = [];
        error(['Could not duplicate the ACCDB template to the directory "' accdb_path '".']);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you again, Tommaso.  With this amount of code overhead, it won't nearly be as attractive to manipulate data in the Matlab environment using SQL.  However, it has been educational.  Based on your minimal working example, I spent an afternoon of trial and error hammering out an example that includes creation of a database table and export of a Matlab table.